# Segmentation fault: 11 on unordered set insertion

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++17, unordered-set

I can't get why is it showing segmentation error with these given values of numbers and target

```
int findind(vector<int> s,int tar, int high , int low ){
    int mid = (high - low)/2;
    if(s.at(mid) == tar){
        return mid;
    }
    else if (tar < s.at(mid)){
        high = mid;
        return findind(s,tar,high,low);
    }
    else{
        low = mid;
        return findind(s,tar,high,low);
    }
}

int main(){
    vector<int> numbers = {-1,0,1,4,5,7};
    int target = 8;
    int id1=-1, id2=-1, N = numbers.size();
    unordered_set<int> us;
    vector<int> ids;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {   if (numbers[i] == target/2 && target%2 == 0){
            if (i!=N-1 && numbers[i+1] == numbers[i])
            {
                id1 = i;
                id2 = i+1;
                break;
            }
            else{
                us.insert(numbers[i]);
            }
        }

        else if(us.find(target - numbers[i]) == us.end()){
            us.insert(numbers[i]);
        }
        else{
            id1 = i;
            id2 = findind(numbers,target - numbers[i],N,0);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(id1 < id2 ){
        ids.push_back(id1+1);
        ids.push_back(id2+1);
    }
    else{
        ids.push_back(id2+1);
        ids.push_back(id1+1);
    }
    cout<<ids[0]<<" "<<ids[1]<<" ";
    return 0; 
}
```

error in sublime text is :

`enter code here`line 1: 67625 Segmentation fault: 11  gtimeout 4s ./TwoSumII-InputArrayIsSorted < inputf.in > outputf.in
[Finished in 1.4s with exit code 139]

and error in leetcode is :

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==30==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffd7e8e8fd8 (pc 0x000000334f91 bp 0x00000000001c sp 0x7ffd7e8e8fd0 T0)
==30==ABORTING
```

also if I put numbers = {3,24,50,79,88,150,345} and target = 200, same error occurs.

But if I comment out us.insert(numbers[i]) in :

```
else if(us.find(target - numbers[i]) == us.end()){
            us.insert(numbers[i]);
}
```

and put cout<<i<<" ";
then it don't give this error

Comment: Looks like infinite or *really deep* recursion. https://godbolt.org/z/7P5z7ncqY Step through the code in a debugger and you'll likely figure out why.

Comment: And while stepping through, see if you can turn on the sanitizer that leetcode used, the groovy `-fsanitize=undefined,address` from Retired Ninja's godbolt link. If you step too far and the program crashes, you at least get a good diagnostic that'll help the next debugger run.

Comment: I the issue is recursion, why did you write a recursive routine?  The same function could have been written iteratively, or better yet `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` could have been used instead of writing your own binary search.  It may look "cool" to write something recursively, but you are running into one of the major drawbacks of doing so -- stack exhaustion.

Comment: Not the source of the problem, but please use a const reference `const vector<int>& s` instead of passing the vector by value `vector<int> s`, which means making a full copy at each iteration.

Comment: If `findind` was correctly written, it would have a stack depth of **O(log n)**, which is the maximum I accept for recursive functions. With  **O(log n)**, normally stack exhaustion is nearly impossible, unlike if it was **O(n)** which is *very* easy to have a stack overflow.

Comment: `int findind(const std::vector<int>& s,int tar) { auto iter = std::lower_bound(s.begin(), s.end(), tar); return std::distance(s.begin(), iter); }`.  Also, since Leetcode is a "competitive coding" website with random puzzles and not a C++ teaching site, isn't the goal to write as less code as possible that gets the job done quickly, i.e. beat everyone in the competition?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on what you intend by your **main** function, but certainly a big part of the problem is that **findind** will run forever if **tar** does not match any value in **s** because the only way out of the function is if it finds a match, satisfying the condition **(s.at(mid) == tar)**.  Otherwise it will recurse, adding another entry on the stack and eventually the stack will overflow.

```
int findind(vector<int> s,int tar, int high , int low ){
    int mid = (high - low)/2;
    if(s.at(mid) == tar){
        return mid;
    }
    else if (tar < s.at(mid)){
        high = mid;
        return findind(s,tar,high,low);
    }
    else{
        low = mid;
        return findind(s,tar,high,low);
    }
}
```

You need to decide what value you want **findind** to return if no match for **tar** is found in **s** and you should return that value if **high == low**.